# Evitar guardar credenciales en el navegador

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs-2.0

¿Cómo puedo evitar que se guarden las credenciales de un usuario dentro del navegador, por ejemplo, Chrome? Estoy realizando dos consultas de autenticación dentro de una sola cuenta ya autenticada. Es mala práctica, pero necesito que los usuarios y contraseñas secundarios no se guarden en el navegador.

Estoy utilizando Angular como Front y Java como back.

Answer (score 1):

agrega el campo autocomplete="off" al input

```
<input type="password" autocomplete="off" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Quizás esto pueda ayudarte.

```
<form action="" method="" name="" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="username"/>
    <input type="password"/>
</form>
```